# ng-fullcalendar eventClick timeStamp not giving correct timeStamp error

Tags: javascript, timestamp, fullcalendar, momentjs, angular6

Hi In my Angular 6 application I am using ng-fullcalendar. 
On clicking fullCalendar event I need to get time slot. When I call eventClick function it's giving a time stamp value, when I convert this unix timestamp to date using moment it always giving 01/01/1970 09:34.

My Template is

```
<ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail, $event)"></ng-fullcalendar>
```

and My TypeScript function

```
 eventClick(model: any, event: MouseEvent) {
     console.log(event.timeStamp);  // giving 293128.0999999726
     console.log('moment  date is : ' + moment(event.timeStamp).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
 }
```

Can anyone tell me why this MouseEvent.timestamp is giving wrong timestamp.

Thank You

[image: My event run for 4 hours and I have details of customers I served]

[image: (click) function not firing]

I Used jQuery mouseover listener , It's working fine but still I can't able to get ID, Class Name attributes of particular td.

```
   let element1 = $(document).on('.fc-minor');
   element1.on(' mouseover', function(event: ElementRef) {
        let va = element1.attr('class');
        let eeee = element1.attr('id');
        console.log('va is: ' + va );
        console.log('eeee is: ' + eeee );
   });
```

Mouseover working good but console logs printing undefined

[image: Console logs for mouseover listener]

Comment: the timestamp you're looking at (if supported by the event in question - not all are, which looks like it might be the case here) is the time the JavaScript click event was generated - i.e. the time you clicked on the event - relative to the time the HTML document was created in the browser. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp . It's nothing whatsoever to do with your calendar events.

Comment: Anyway in fullCalendar it's not possible to get the exact timeslot clicked on within an event, unfortunately. What are you actually trying to achieve which requires that information? Perhaps there's another way

Comment: Hi @ADyson thanks for the info. I want to know how many customers we  are serving per hour. So based on the time slot event click I will update that customer count in my template.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic. What do you categorise as "serving" a customer? If they simply click on a time in your calendar is that enough? Or do they need to actually do something like purchase a product or make an appointment? What is the reason the customer is clicking on some existing event? I'm not quite clear of the flow of your business process.

Comment: @ADyson above the calendar I have a form where I show number of customers served between the selected time .

Comment: Ok i see, you're trying to look at existing data stored in the event? I thought you were trying to capture new data. It's still not totally clear. You still didn't define "served". But anyway...if you want to know number of customers per hour, you'd have to have separate events, one per hour, then you'd know exactly which hour was clicked. That's the bottom line in all of this - it simply isn't possible to know in fullCalendar when an event is clicked on, precisely which part of the event it was.

Comment: Hi Adyson, I modified fullcalendar.js file and added id, name, class, (click) attributes. But, when I click on td it's not firing the click event. Could you please let me know what was the problem. Please see the image attached

Comment: well I can't see what click event you're putting on your td, but also you've given them all the same ID which is not allowed in HTML. The whole point of the ID is to uniquely identify an element.

Comment: Adyson, <td (click)="Create()"> , Yes I know ID should be unique. I am trying to access click event and getting class name.

Comment: " I know ID should be unique"...in that case why have you made them all the same??

Comment: Anyway I think perhapsd your issue is that `element1` is not an element, it's an  event handler. Perhaps instead of `let element1 = $(document).on('.fc-minor');
   element1.on(' mouseover', function(event: ElementRef) {` you meant simply `$(document).on('mouseover', '.fc-minor', function(event: ElementRef) {` ? That would allow for proper delegated event handling (and removes the incorrect empty space before "mouseover"). Then within the function itself you can use `this` to get the clicked element e.g. `this.attr("class")`

Comment: btw mouseover is not click...you keep referring to a click event but the new code is all about mouseover. If you want to handle a click on .fc-minor then just replace "mouseover" with "click" in my sample above

Comment: Adyson, Thanks for that, When I right click I am not getting  element , But I am getting my required time on mouseover ( I am updating my variable value when ever you move the mouse ) On right clicking I am getting that value. `$('tr.fc-minor.KRISHN').mouseover(function() {
     if ( $(this).attr('name') != null ) {
      timeSlotClicked = $(this).attr('name');
     }`
    }); Thanks

Comment: click will only respond to left-click, not right-click. How are you detecting right-click? I sense that I'm not seeing all your code.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is not working because the value its returning is wrong. Use the `dayClick` event to get the date with all the details:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
      alert('clicked ' + date.format());
}
```

Here is a demo link that I have forked:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo-vm394f

Comment: thanks for dayClick, but I need ng-reflect-selected-timeslot value of eventClick. My event is 4 hours long and I exactly need that time.

Comment: I checked eventClick but there is no information about the particular date.

Comment: (dayClick) only fires when we click on day and (eventClick) on event , So I can't use dayClick value.

Comment: "The timestamp is not working because the value its returning is wrong"...this is a tautology. OP is asking _why_ it returns an unexpected value.